# Elasticsearch Date Histogram Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to do a date histogram query that lists the connections per brand_eid per day. I need the response formatted so that I can feed the data straight into the graphing app. My current query is as follows:

```
 "aggregations": {
  "connections": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key_as_string": "02-Oct",
           "key": 1380672000000,
           "doc_count": 1,
           "brand": {
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": 2,
                    "doc_count": 62
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 7,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 12,
                    "doc_count": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 8,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 11,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "key_as_string": "17-Oct",
           "key": 1381968000000,
           "doc_count": 46,
           "brand": {
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": 2,
                    "doc_count": 44
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 7,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 },
                 {
                    "key": 8,
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        }   
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to rewrite this query so that the response back is like:

```
Aggregations
    connect_date
        buckets
            Object
                key2: 1
                key7: 3
                doc_count: 4
                key: 1380672000000
                key_as_string: "2013-10-02T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Is this possible without having to manipulate the response and restructure the objects client side?

Comment: Just manipulate the response, elasticsearch doesn't give you how you need.

Answer (score 0):

Post the response as it is from elasticsearch. Why dont you read terms and counts as you need and create a json and feed that json to you graphing app?

Comment: Updated with response from elastic. I am new to elastic and I just though that this would be a common query that would not need to be manipulated into a new structure (ie: graphing error logs by application per day on a stacked column chart)

Comment: It will be better if you create your own json by reading doc_count of buckets you need because you dont want to provide unnecessary fields and provide only what you need to plot the graph.

Answer (score -1):

For above response why dont you have something like this:

```
{
  "02-Oct": {
    "2": "62",
    "7": "2",
    "8": "1",
    "11": "1",
    "12": "2"
  },
  "17-Oct": {
    "2": "44",
    "7": "1",
    "8": "1"
  }
}
```